# Make `Autowired` inside the run method

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a small spinet of Java code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import me.cimply.ask.odata.repository.*;

@Component
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Runner.class);

    @Autowired
    private IconRepository iconRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        this.fillRepository(iconRepository);
        this.fillRepository(userRepository);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private void fillRepository(BaseRepository repository) {
       // Code
    }
}
```

I want to make this code as generic as possible.

I would like to extract the names of all the interfaces inside the `me.cimply.ask.odata.repository` package and generate the instances of them in a loop in the `run` method or in the constructor of the class and invoke the `fillRepository` method for them.

In the other word, I would like to only add **new** interfaces inside the `me.cimply.ask.odata.repository` package and the above code is run for them too, without adding any new line of code each time here. Something like this **pseudocode**:

```java
import me.cimply.ask.odata.repository.*;

@Component
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Runner.class);

    private BaseRepository repositories[];

    public Runner(){
       for(InterfaceX in me.cimply.ask.odata.repository.*){
          repositories.push(new Autowired instance of InterfaceX);
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        for(repo in repositories)
           this.fillRepository(repo);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private void fillRepository(BaseRepository repository) {
       // Code
    }
}
```

Please note `BaseRepository` is an interface in the `me.cimply.ask.odata.repository` package that all other interfaces implement that!

I searched a lot, and it seems the `Autowired` must be defined as a class property, anyway maybe someone know a technique to implement this idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every of your repositories implement `BaseRepository`, then you can do that:

```java
import me.cimply.ask.odata.repository.*;

@Component
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private List<BaseRepository> repositories;

    @Autowired
    public Runner(List<BaseRepository> repositories){
       this.repositories = repositories;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        for(BaseRepository repo : repositories)
           this.fillRepository(repo);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private void fillRepository(BaseRepository repository) {
       // Code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have several beans implementing a common interface, define a dependency on the list of interfaces and Spring will give you all the available implementations:

```
@Component
public class Runner {
    private final List<Interface> beans;

    @Autowired
    public Runner(final List<Interface> beans) {
        this.beans = beans;
        // beans will contain Bean1, Bean2, Bean3
    }
}

public interface Interface {}

@Component
public class Bean1 implements Interface {}

@Component
public class Bean2 implements Interface {}

@Component
public class Bean3 implements Interface {}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. But let me accept the answer of @dominikbrandon, as he has less scores and provided a complete answer few seconds before you.